# Conditional login not working in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check admin login But it does not work although I echo some value.

What is my problem I try to find many days but I can't found it everything if I echo from `My_controller` it will show on Frontend and Backend(admin) but If I echo from my Admin (Backend) it will show nothing.

Event `$this->data['admin_site']=  config_item('admin_site');`

I can't get `admin_site` value for variable that I will echo on header `<title>echo $admin_site</title>`

But If I put `$this->data['admin_site']=  config_item('admin_site');`  in `My_Controller` it will work.

```
<?PHP
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller{

    public function __contruct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['admin_site']=  config_item('admin_site');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session'); 
        $this->load->model('user_m');
        $this->load->model('page_m');
        $this->load->model('admin/slide/slider_m'); 
        $this->load->model("user_m");

        $strurl = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $adminlogged_in  =  $this->user_m->loggedin();
         if(trim($strurl)  == "admin" || !empty($strurl )){
             if(trim($adminlogged_in)  == FALSE){
                redirect('admin/user/login');
             } 
         } 
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Spelling problem:**
`__construct()`, not `__contruct()` at `Admin_Controller`

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from the text what exactly the issue is.  Are you suggesting that the problem is solved by using `$this->data['admin_site']`?

If you want people to debug your code for you here you should make it less chatty - for example In CI you need to read configuration variables set in configuration files as follows - `$this->config->item('admin_site');` - there is no reason for you to write a wrapper function to do this - it just makes code messy.

Another issue is that you have `$adminlogged_in` set and only used once.  There is no need - just run the check on the method - and why would you be trimming and running a comparison on a boolean?

Clarify the question and clean up the code and you will get an answer in no time.